# Mysql Use Insert with conditions and value from select satement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table m4zbv_mt_cfvalues and like to insert a record if a record dosn't exist with the same values in cf_id and link_id

I like to do this inserts for all records from a select statement, link_id should be used for the first condition and on the insert.

```
INSERT INTO m4zbv_mt_cfvalues (cf_id, link_id,value) 
 SELECT 87, link_id ,1
 FROM dual 
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
    ( SELECT *
      FROM m4zbv_mt_cfvalues
      WHERE cf_id = 87
        AND link_id = link_id
    )
    SELECT link_id from from m4zbv_mt_links where Upper(link_name) like'%APPLIANCE  DEFAULT PASSWORDS%' ;
```

The Insert is working if I supply all values. It stops working when I add the Select link_id statement.
I can't figure out how to get all records on the select condition and the link_id from table m4zbv_mt_links

Thanks for any help

Manfred

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I receive still the error above. It seems the filed link_id is not correctly passed. Do you have an idea how to correct this error? The field link_id exists on both tables.

Thanks

Regrads Manfred

Answer (score 0):

your code is like that

```
 SELECT link_id from from
```

just remove one `FROM`

try this

```
   INSERT INTO m4zbv_mt_cfvalues (cf_id, link_id,value) 
    SELECT 87, link_id ,1
    FROM dual 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS
             ( SELECT *
              FROM m4zbv_mt_cfvalues
              WHERE cf_id = 87
              AND link_id = (SELECT link_id from m4zbv_mt_links where Upper(link_name) like'%APPLIANCE  DEFAULT PASSWORDS%')
)
 ;
```

Comment: "#1054 - Unknown column 'link_id' in 'field list'" Thanks for the reply but I receive still the error above. It seems the filed link_id is not correctly passed. Do you have an idea how to correct this error? The field link_id exists on both tables.